# Flutter SQFLite how to query a column value and show it in the UI

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Using Flutter SQFLite, I have a table with one row.

The code below creates and saves the record in the database.

Now, I want to display the saved value stored in the database.

I know I need to query the database, but I am not quite sure how to display the saved database value in the UI.

Here is the example code - how do I show value from the database in the UI?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() {runApp(MyApp());}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class DataFields {
  static final List<String> values = [id, name];
  static final String id = '_id';
  static final String name = 'myName';
}

class DataModel{
  int id;
  String name;
  DataModel({required this.id, required this.name});

  DataModel copy({int? id,String? title,String? description,int? 
  isSelected}) => DataModel(id: id ?? this.id,name: name ?? 
  this.name);
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {if (id != null) 
  DataFields.id: id,DataFields.name: name};
  static DataModel fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => 
  DataModel(id: json[DataFields.id] as int,name: 
  json[DataFields.name] as String);
 }


class DBHelper {
  final String myTable = 'myDataTable';
  static const String myDatabase = 'myDB.db';

  DBHelper._init();
  static final DBHelper instance = DBHelper._init();
  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get dataBase async {
    if (_database != null) {return _database!;} else {
      _database = await _initDB(myDatabase);
      return _database!;
    }
  }

  Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: 
   _createDB);
  }

  Future _createDB(Database db, int version) async {
    var idType = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT';
    var textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';
    await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE $myTable (${DataFields.id} 
  $idType,${DataFields.name} $textType)''');
  }

  Future<DataModel> create(DataModel datamodel) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final id = await db.insert(myTable, datamodel.toJson());
    return datamodel.copy(id: id);
  }

  Future<DataModel> readData(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final maps = await db.query(myTable,columns: 
    DataFields.values,where: '${DataFields.id} = ?',whereArgs: 
     [id]);
    if (maps.isNotEmpty) {return DataModel.fromJson(maps.first);} 
  else {throw Exception('ID $id not found');}
  }

  Future<List<DataModel>> readAllData() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $myTable');
    return result.map((json) => 
  DataModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Future<int> countAllDataRows() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    var x = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM $myTable');
    return x.length;
  }

  Future<int> update(DataModel datamodel) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return db.update(myTable,datamodel.toJson(),where: 
  '${DataFields.id} = ?',whereArgs: [datamodel.id]);
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return await db.delete(myTable,where: '${DataFields.id} = 
   ?',whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future close() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    db.close();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController mc = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController mcNum = TextEditingController();
  int index = 0;
  int myindex = 0;

  addItem() {setState(() {if (mc.text.isNotEmpty) {
    index++;
    DBHelper.instance.create(DataModel(id:index,name:mc.text));
  }});}

  removeItem() {
    setState(() {
      if (index >0){
        DBHelper.instance.delete(index);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget space = SizedBox(width: 100, height: 5, child: 
    Text(""));
    Widget myinput = TextField(controller: 
     mc,decoration:InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), 
     labelText: 'Name'));
    Widget btnAdd = ElevatedButton(onPressed: addItem, child: 
    Text('Add'));
    Widget btnRemove = ElevatedButton(onPressed: removeItem, 
     child: Text('Remove'));

   return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: 
   false,body: SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: 
  Axis.vertical,child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: 
  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: 
 MainAxisSize.min,children: <Widget>[
 Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),child: 
 SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: 
 MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,children: <Widget> 
 [space,space,myinput,space,btnAdd,space,btnRemove, 
 space])))]))));
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: please provide more detail what you want !

Comment: Hello. I really need help how to show name field in the UI. I added a simple example. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

It's better to divide the class to files!do not write all of your codes in on place.
so for achieving this you need to have list of you data model in screen which fills when ever the read all method calls so you could do this .

```dart
List<DataModel>_myDatas=[];
 
_loadAllData()async{
  await DBHelper.instance.readAllData().then((List<DataModel>datas){
  setState((){
 _myDatas=datas;});
});
}

@override 
void initState(){
 super.initiSate();
 _loadAllData();
}
```

then you could use the ‌`_myDatas` for your listView or your aproches
if it doesn't help you I suggest you to watch tutorials in YouTube

Comment: I need to look at a single value to get the value of a True/False flag (zero or one). Another issue is how to do I convert Future function into string? Thank You

Comment: you mean , you want to get single data model and  get that if its true or false ?

Comment: Yes. I need to get single data model and get if it is true or false.